# Cannot get Worksoft EM script to execute

Tags: automated-tests, gui-testing

In Worksoft Certify Execution Manager, I have the below error.

How can I resolve this issue?

I have allowed this port in inbound rule in Firewall. But cannot get the script to execute.

**Error**:

> 4/26/2017 4:10:36 PM:  The Certify workstation at [net.tcp://IP:4242/WorksoftExecutionAgentService] could not be found: [Could not connect to net.tcp://IP:4242/WorksoftExecutionAgentService. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0155272. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it IP:4242. ]

Context: SAP testing.

Answer (score 0):

We have exactly the same error message since we update to the "worksoft Certify Execution Manager" Version 10.0.0.1011.

Nevertheless, the code TCP error was a little different (code 10060) but i hope this solution can help you.

After many hours checking Firewall inbound and outbound rules in our Firewall  and analyses Worksoft log, we found that the problem is coming from a simple user credential issue.

They is no clear explanation or alerting in worksoft to explain this problem, that the reason why we spend a lot of time troubleshooting a simple issue.
We have to add the Domain name manually (DomainName\User) in resource users field and then everything is working fine.

Worksoft will have to improve their error messages. 
Furthermore an example on the Resources Users field will be welcome.

Comment: try to provide solution instead of describing only your issue.